# VS2015 and C++ Service fail to auto-start

Tags: c++, service, visual-studio-2015

I am facing a strange issue with VS2015. When compiling a service (I had this issue with my own code base, but was able to reproduce it on the basic service sample from MSDN https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppWindowsService-cacf4948), the service will fail to auto-start on a fresh install of Windows 10.

Here’s the repro steps of the problem:

1. Take a basic C++ service code (We took one from MSDN) and compile
   it with Visual Studio 2015
2. Install it on a fresh install of
   Windows 10 with automatic startup
3. Do a cold reboot

Result : The service won’t start, even with automatic delayed set.

Now the funny part… there are several work-around for this issue:

1. If you manually start the service before the cold reboot, it will
   be fine
2. If you restart (not reboot) the machine after your cold
   reboot, the service will start
3. On some machines (not Fresh Windows 10 install, the problem does not happen)
4. Build the service with VS2013 won't cause this issue.

Because I need to use VS2015 (My service should be using the Windows 10 SDK), I would like to know if there is any solution or if this is simply a bug with VS2015.

Thanks

Js

Comment: How do you install the service ? Win32 Create/Start Service or Powershell Or sc.exe ... ?

Comment: 32 bit or 64 bit service and OS?

Comment: It happens with both 32 and 64 bit version. The service is install using "sc create".

Comment: 1 - what is a "cold reboot" ; 2- What is the exact sequence of click and command lines you are typing ?

Comment: 1 - A cold reboot implies poweroff the PC  2 - After compiling my service I type : sc create TestService binpath="[Path to my executable]" start= auto